# how to access dynamically created dom elements values from another functions' event listener

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my form elements with javascript dynamically, as I can not use html form, as it becomes static on page. On click I'd like to trigger an event handling from another function, but nothing is happening there

HTML form will not work, as this form is created on every call by user, it's a comment box under each video frame.

```js
function createCommentForm() {
  var fc = document.createElement("form");
  fc.setAttribute('name', "formC");
  var it = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
  it.setAttribute('type', "text");
  it.setAttribute('name', "comment");
  var ib = document.createElement("input"); //input button, button
  ib.setAttribute('type', "submit");
  ib.setAttribute('name', "btnC");
  ib.setAttribute('value', "add comment");
  ib.onclick = function() {
    return false
  }; //doesnt go to another page on click
  fc.appendChild(it);
  fc.appendChild(ib);
  document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(fc);
}

function addComment(urlX) {
  createCommentForm();
  var btnC = document.getElementById("button");
  btnC.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var cmt = 'data=' + urlX + '.txtbreakpoint' + document.getElementById("comment").value;
    //data must be passed somehow as its need by $_POST in save.php file
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response = document.createElement("p");
    document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(response);
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
      response.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ssave.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(cmt);
    console.log(cmt + ' 2');
    //document.getElementById('formC').reset(); //clear form fields
  });
}
```

Comment: You mean `document.getElementById("div3").getElementsByName("btnC")[0].click()` ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("comment")` <-- there's nothing in the above code with an ID of `comment`.  Change it to `document.querySelector("[name=comment]")`  (This assumes there's only 1 element with the name `comment`)

Comment: oh my god, absolutely, gosh i never paid attention on that id thing, yes absolutely i changed the name to id and WHOALA... gosh it works  love this community  yeah brothers thank U all....!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to `getElementById()` using this id `button`, but you even didn't set it to the created button.

```
var btnC = document.getElementById("button");
                                    ^
```

**Set the id as follow:**

```
ib.id = 'button';
```

## Look at this code snippet

```js
function createCommentForm() {
  var fc = document.createElement("form");
  fc.setAttribute('name', "formC");
  var it = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
  it.setAttribute('type', "text");
  it.setAttribute('name', "comment");
  var ib = document.createElement("input"); //input button, button
  ib.setAttribute('type', "submit");
  ib.setAttribute('name', "btnC");
  ib.setAttribute('value', "add comment");
  ib.id = 'button';
  ib.onclick = function() {
    return false
  }; //doesnt go to another page on click
  fc.appendChild(it);
  fc.appendChild(ib);
  document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(fc);
}

function addComment(urlX) {
  createCommentForm();
  var btnC = document.getElementById("button");
  btnC.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('Ajax call!')
    
    
    /*
    var cmt = 'data=' + urlX + '.txtbreakpoint' + document.getElementById("comment").value;
    //data must be passed somehow as its need by $_POST in save.php file
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response = document.createElement("p");
    document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(response);
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
      response.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ssave.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(cmt);
    console.log(cmt + ' 2');
    //document.getElementById('formC').reset(); //clear form fields
    */
  });
}

addComment('urlX');
```

```html
<div id='div3'></div>
```

See? the function is called.

Comment: beautiful !!! briliant !!! rock n roll !!!! it works like a swiss watch !!! thanks sooooo much, i spent almost 4hours thinking of each line, changing file names and resetting the sever, gosh it was simply an id id id id id

Answer (score -1):

You are searching for an element by `id` called `comment`, but your element has a `name` of `comment`. Changing the selector fixes the issue.

However, your code should be modified a bit. If you aren't going to submit the data anywhere (via the traditional `submit` button), don't use a submit button only to cancel the `sumbit` event. Instead use a regular `button`.

And, the code could be modernized.

```js
function createCommentForm(){
  var fc = document.createElement("form");
  fc.name = "formC";
  var it = document.createElement("input");
  it.type = "text";
  it.name = "comment";
  var ib = document.createElement("input");
  ib.type ="button";
  ib.name = "btnC";
  ib.value = "add comment";
  ib.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
    var cmt = 'data=' + it.value + '.txtbreakpoint' + document.querySelector("[name=comment]").value;
    //data must be passed somehow as its need by $_POST in save.php file
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response = document.createElement("p");
    document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(response);
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
      response.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ssave.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(cmt);
    console.log(cmt + ' 2');
    //document.getElementById('formC').reset(); //clear form fields
  });
  fc.appendChild(it);
  fc.appendChild(ib);
  document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(fc);
}

createCommentForm();
```

```html
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Comment: thank u so much , great help, i learned alot  will do all the further codes in modern way from now on, thank Much !!!! appretiate your time and help Sir.